# Shell Context Menu - Shortcut to folder

Tags: windows, shell, contextmenu

Is it possible to create a Windows context menu which jumps to a folder (changing the current shell's working directory).

Comment: Take a look here [howtogeek](https://www.google.com.br/amp/s/www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/customize-the-windows-vista-send-to-menu/amp/)

Comment: By shell, do you mean cmd.exe or Explorer?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "jumps to"? Do you really mean "changing the current directory of the explorer process"? That doesn't jump anywhere, and it's not visible to the end user.